# Set Multibing for text - get and set

Tags: wpf, mvvm, multibinding

I would like to bind my `TextBox.Text` to two different sources.

I have 2 `ViewModel`s, one is general `ViewModel` and one is more specific (which is inherit from its parent).

Both `ViewModel`s has a property called "Hotkey".

I would like to bind my `TextBox.Text` so it will get the value from the general `ViewModel` and set it to the specific `ViewModel`.

I tried the following:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#000">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource test}">
            <Binding Path="DataContext.Hotkey" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MetroStyle:MetroWindow}}" Mode="OneWay" />
            <Binding Path="Hotkey" Mode="OneWayToSource"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

It does get the value from the general `ViewModel`, but it doesn't set its value to the specific one (which inherits from the parent)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem may be in the Converter you used for `MultiBinding`, I've just tried a simple demo and looks like that Converter should be implemented like this:

```
public class TestConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private bool justConvertedBack;
    object IMultiValueConverter.Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
                     object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (justConvertedBack) {
            justConvertedBack = false;
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
        return values[0];
    }

    object[] IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
                     object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        justConvertedBack = true;
        return new object[] {null, value};
    }
}
```

It happens that after the `ConvertBack` has been done, the `Convert` will be triggered and keep the Text of your TextBox unchanged (although you tried deleting/modifying it before). So we need some flag `justConvertedBack` here to prevent that from occurring.

Currently changing the source from the general ViewModel will change the TextBox's Text ***but*** does not update the source from the specific ViewModel. However if setting/typing some value for the TextBox's Text will update the source from the specific ViewModel but won't reflect that value back to the source from the general ViewModel. I hope that behavior is what you want.